# Bookdown - conditional display of text and code blocks (LaTeX/PDF vs. HTML)

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using R markdown (Bookdown) and want to accomplish the following:

````
## Section

This is some text. I want this to be visibile in Bookdown/HTML but not in Bookdown/PDF

Also in-line statements containing things like `var_a` need to be conditionally displayed.
 
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE, eval = !knitr::is_latex_output()}
### codeblock will not appear in pdf but only in html, this seems to work
print(1+1)
)
````

I was able to make the codeblock conditional. How can I accomplish the same for the rest? Putting the other text in a codeblock via `cat("string")` is not a suitable approach for me. A potential related solution might be to try to exclude the whole subsection from PDF but keep it in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be wrapping the whole text and codes (i.e. contents in general) that you want to show conditionally within a pandoc div `:::` and using pandoc lua filter to conditionally include that div depending on output format.

So you can use the following lua filter **`conditional-content.lua`** to do this.

**conditional-content.lua**

```
function Div(el)
  if el.attributes['show-in'] then
    if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
      if el.attributes['show-in'] == "html" then
        el.content = ""
        return el
      end
    elseif FORMAT:match 'html' then
      if el.attributes['show-in'] == 'pdf' then
        el.content = ""
        return el
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Attach the filter in the  `_output.yml` file using `pandoc_args` yaml key.

**_output.yml**

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=conditional-content.lua"]
  css: style.css
  theme:
    primary: "#096B72"
  repo: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo
bookdown::pdf_book:
  pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=conditional-content.lua"]
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
```

Then write the conditional contents by wrapping the contents within pandoc divs and using the attribute `show-in`. For contents to be included in pdf output only, use `show-in="pdf"`, and for contents to be included in html output only, use `show-in="html"`.

````
# Hello bookdown 

::: {show-in="pdf"}

This would be shown only in pdf

```{r}
print("from pdf")
```

:::


::: {show-in="html"}

This would be shown only in html

```{r}
print("from html")
```

:::


This would be shown in both pdf and html
````

which would produce the following output after rendering,

---

**for pdf output format**

[image: contents in pdf output format]

---

**for html output format**

[image: contents in html output format]

---