# How to show block of markdown when knitting to HTML, but not when output format is PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating a report which I want to render to HTML and PDF, depending on the command I choose from RStudio (Knit to PDF, Knit to HTML).

A chapter should contain a datatable, which should be incorporated in the HTML output, but not in the PDF output. But not only the datatable should be added depending on the output format (which works anyway because kniting to PDF just does not add it), the whole chapter should be avoided when rendering to PDF.

The chapter contains some markdown code to add a chapter heading and some text. Maybe later it will get some R chunks, but for now I can go on without R chunks inside that chapter.
And as the report is not that big, I dont want to fiddle around with child documents.

The MWE:

````
---
title: "MWE"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
date: '2023-05-29'
---

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(DT)
```

## Chapter 1

MWE to check if conditional blocks work, depending on output format (PDF, HTML)

```{r, cars}
plot(cars)
```
```{=html}

## Chapter 2

This chapter should only be shown when output format is PDF, as datatable wont work on PDF.

```

```{r, dt, eval=knitr::pandoc_to() == 'html'}
datatable(cars)
```
````

When rendering to PDF, the chapter is omitted, which is good. But when rendering to HTMl, the chapters markdown code is not formatted as markdown.

[image: HTML with rendering problems]

I made another attempt to use Pandoc:

Second MWE:

````
---
title: "MWE"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
date: '2023-05-29'
---

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(DT)
```

## Chapter 1

MWE to check if conditional blocks work, depending on output format (PDF, HTML)

```{r, cars}
plot(cars)
```

::: {.content-visible when-format="html"}

## Chapter 2

This chapter should only be shown when output format is PDF, as datatable wont work on PDF.

```{r, dt1, eval=knitr::pandoc_to() == 'html'}
datatable(cars)
```

:::
````

This time, the formatting on the HTML output is fine, but the chapter now appears in the PDF output as well (only the markdown and text content, not the datatable!). Even tried setting the format to "latex" as `knitr::pandoc_to()` reports `latex`, but it still appears in the output PDF.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76255913/10858321) might solve your problem.